# Where to initialize the usercontrol properties before databinding?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, user-controls

How can I write the C# code (aspx) to initialize the user control with some default property values? I mean where/which event? I have a user control with a gridview that I bind on container page. On page load of the container page I bind the data. I tried writing the initialization code in initproperties but it didn't work. Please suggest where can I set the default values for my usercontrol?

Edited:
As suggested by DOK.. I already have a property and I change width of one of the DIVs. Here is the code that is not working.

```
public int CollapsiblePanelWidth
    {
        set
        {
            if (DataDiv.Attributes["style"] != null)
            {
                if (DataDiv.Attributes["style"].Contains("width:"))
                {
                    string[] array = DataDiv.Attributes["style"].Split(new char[] { ';' });
                    array = Array.FindAll(array, ContainsWidthAttribute);
                    string result = "";
                    foreach (string s in array)
                    {
                        result += s + "; ";
                    }                   
                    DataDiv.Attributes["style"] = result + " width: " + Convert.ToString(value != null ? value : COLLAPSIBLEPANELWIDTH) + "px;";
                }
                else
                {
                    DataDiv.Attributes["style"] += " width: " + Convert.ToString(value != null? value:COLLAPSIBLEPANELWIDTH) + "px;";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                DataDiv.Attributes.Add("style", "width: " + Convert.ToString(value != null ? value : COLLAPSIBLEPANELWIDTH) + "px;");
            }
            GridView1.Width = Unit.Parse(Convert.ToString(value != null ? value : COLLAPSIBLEPANELWIDTH - 2));
        }
    }
```

This works only if I set the width on calling program. Otherwise the default value of `style="width: 105px;"` is not added.

Comment: well since it will be called every time you postback, why don't you write it directly under page_load of your parent form under If(Page.IsPostBack) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you want is dummy property CollapsiblePanelWidth that just handles taking a width or returning the default if it hasn't been set.

Then do your style setting code in the `override void OnPreRender(EventArgs)` method of your UserControl.

Edit: Something like this should be sufficient

```
public MyUserControl()
{
    CollapsiblePanelWidth = 105;
}

public int CollapsiblePanelWidth { get; set; }

protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    DataDiv.Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width] = CollapsiblePanelWidth.ToString();
    GridView1.Width = CollapsiblePanelWidth - 2;

    base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```

Comment: but OnPreRender is called after the Page_load event of the container page. User sets the width in page_load and it is overriden with my defaults values in prerender.

Comment: @user465876: I've added a code sample to show what I mean.  The default is set in the constructor.  So if the user doesn't change it, the default is used.  If the user changes it, the user's choice is used.  I've also simplified your Style setting code.

Comment: Greg, You are great! Thanks for the wonderful solution with simple code to understand. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

How about creating **properties of the UserControl** and giving them a default value? Those properties will be set when the UserControl is initialized, and you can change them in code.

You can specify access to the properties as public or private or protected. Then, you can alter public properties from the parent.

Perhaps you can alter your code to something real simple until you get that existing property to work. Remove the possibility that it's the code that's the problem, and not the property itself. Get the property working, and then make it do something complicated.

Comment: I actually have a property but doesn't seem to work. Basically, I only have a Set property and I set the width of the DIV. Something like: DataDiv.Attributes["style"] += " width: " + Convert.ToString(value != null? value:COLLAPSIBLEPANELWIDTH) + "px;";
I want the div to get the default value if user doesn't specify it on his page.